# expression must be a modifiable L value

Tags: pointers

I have the code snippet where i get the error expression must be a modifiable L value.

node1.h

```
class node{
int data;

public:
node* next;
node(){}
void setdata(int a){data=a;}
char getdata(){return data;}
node* Next(){
return next;}
                  };
```

list.cpp

```
#include"node1.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
class list{
node* first;
public:
list(){first=NULL;}
 void list::append(char data){
 node * tmp=first;
 node* newnode=new node;
    newnode->setdata(data);

    tmp->Next()=newnode;//line 1
    tmp->next=newnode;//line 2
}
 }
```

line1 gives error that expression must be a modifiable l value,but should'nt line1 and line2 do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the value of `Next` because it's a function.